# How sharp are the bits of sand and rock on mars?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, regolith

Lunar regolith is quite sharp, so abrasive [it can cut kevlar](https://perryponders.com/2015/03/03/surface-of-moon-can-cut-through-kevlar/).

This is because there is no flowing water or substantial atmosphere to erode the material and smoothen it out, so meteorite impacts break it up even more, and it stays sharp like broken glass.

What about mars? The martian atmosphere is somewhat substantial, at [almost 0.7% of the earth's in terms of pressure](https://marsed.asu.edu/mep/atmosphere), and there is quite a bit of wind too.

**How sharp are rocks and the regolith on Mars?**

Please compare it to the earth and the moon in your answer.

Comment: You sure the data from the various landers doesn't include this info?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If you could find it please post it as an answer

Comment: I am honestly curious - how is this measured?  Are there units of sharpness?  +1 just to find that out.

Comment: @OrganicMarble maybe have a scale of a few materials ordered by toughness, and see where they stop getting cut?

Comment: It's not the sharpness (though that's probably part of the problem), but the bigger problem seems to be the the size (very fine) and stickiness (electrically charged).    This article suggests that Mars is comparable to the moon in that regards:   https://futurism.com/extraterrestrial-dust-moon-mars-health

Comment: @OrganicMarble  "sharpness" is quite simply the measured angle of surface irregularities, just as one would evaluate a knife blade.  Oh, and with an evaluation of any 'roundedness" along each edge.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft what are the units?

Comment: @OrganicMarble   radians and  nanofurlongs :-)